# why assign (x, y) parameter to the instance variables in the Test class like this?

Tags: java

```
public class Test{

    public int a = 0;

    public int b = 0;

    public Test(int x, int y) {

        a = x;

        a = y;

    }
}
```

so my question here is why provide arguments x,y in the constructor and set them equal to the instance variables? is it perhaps so each object created from class Test can initialize the variables in its own way?

Comment: My question is "Why not?"

Comment: If they are public then its is useless cause you can do test.a or test.b directly.

Comment: Can you explain what the rest of the problem is?

Comment: I guess the last line should be `b = y`?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You can assign method parameters to whatever you want to assign them to.

Comment: Maybe have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question

Comment: From the very vague information that you have given, it seems like x and y are just being used because they can be. Anything can be used in the place of x and y.

Answer (score 1):

From the look of your question, I guess you probably feel that the arguments in the class constructor should follow the name of the instance variables.

```
class MyClass{
    int varA;
    int varB;

    public MyClass(int varA, int varB){
        this.varA = varA;
        this.varB = varB;
    }
}
```

However, this is just a convention (which not even everyone follows). You can simply provide a different variable name and you will have something like this:

```
class MyClass{
    int varA;
    int varB;

    public MyClass(int _varA, int _varB){
        this.varA = _varA;
        this.varB = _varB;
    }
}
```

Or even this..

```
class MyClass{
    int varA;
    int varB;

    public MyClass(int _varA, int _varB){
        varA = _varA;  //"this" is optional here
        varB = _varB;  //"this" is optional here
    }
}
```

In the last code example, "this" keyword is optional because it is distinguishable between a variable from the argument list and the instance variable.

Since we can use different variable names for the constructor, (E.g. `_varA` instead of `varA`). We can also use a entirely different variable name such as (`x` and `y`). Hence answering your question.

---

On top of that, you can even choose not to initialize your variables in the class.(You can do this, but not necessarily mean you should). Or having a constructor which do not receive any arguments yet, initializing the instance variables. You have the freedom to do anything you want to your self-defined class constructor.

Comment: You have syntax errors.  I edited once but you overwrote my edits :-(

Comment: Yeah. You put "this.varB; = _varB;"